# What are all the declarations in PHP?

Tags: php, declaration

I don't know if "declaration" is the right word for what I'm asking. It might be "definition" or something else.

PHP does not declare variables. You just define them by assigning a value.

But there are certain keywords that declare the existence of a new entity: `const`, `function`, `class`, and `interface`. They all have the same syntax:

```
keyword EntityName code
```

as in

```
const ConstantName = 1;
function FunctionName {...}
class ClassName {...}
interface InterfaceName {...}
```

I don't see anywhere in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/) where these keywords are discussed together but they definitely seem to play a kind of top-level role in the language. Each of them is documented in their own respective sections of the manual, but I wonder if there's a useful way to think about them in terms of the analogous roles they play. And are there other keywords in that category besides those four? Is there any combined documentation about them?

Comment: They wouldn't really be discussed together, as they represent different parts of the programming language. One defines a variable which cannot be changed, another an anonymous/declared function, etc...

Comment: From the PHP Manual, you can see a list of reserved keywords which may be what you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Answer (score 0):

Despite PHP is a "weak type" language (so you can't declare variable types), PHP7 strenghtened the type protection (if strict_types is set to 1).

You can't declare a type in lines of code but you can asset them within functions declaration.

i.e.

```
function myfunction(float $a, float $b) : int {
  return $a + $b;
}
```

Please note that we are declaring $a, $b types and the return type.

Another feature that allows you to "declare" variable types is the "new" operator (as many other OOP languages).  With "new" you will instantiate your classes and this will never vary unless you perform a dynamic binding or casting.

Just to clarify the concepts you mention:

- const : Declare a class constant (From PHP 5.3 you can use const outside classes also).
- function: Classical PHP function/method declaration. PHP7 allows you to set parameter types and return types.
- class : Class declaration.
- interface: Interface declaration (special base class definition that can't have any implementation without inheritance).

Some useful resources for beginners.

(PHP7 OOP)
http://www.brainbell.com/tutorials/php/php7-oop-beginners.html
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php (from @Jacin comment)

(PHP7 types)
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php7/php7_returntype_declarations.htm
http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/5-new-features-php-7

Comment: "you can't use const outside from a class": This is not true. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php : "You can define a constant by using the define()-function or by using the const keyword outside a class definition as of PHP 5.3.0."